# How to deploy only select files through BitBucket

Tags: php, mercurial

I'm hosting a small php-based website through Bitbucket. I have some files under version control that I don't want to deploy in production (helpful scripts, `.xcf` files, etc). Is there some way to just send the files I want to the production server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot make Mercurial send only some files. By "send", I guess you mean `hg pull` or maybe `wget https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repo>/get/default.zip`.

The normal way to solve this is to make a dedicated script for deployment. Something like:

```
cd repo
hg pull
hg archive -r production -X util -X imgs/*.xcf site
rsync -av site server:public_html
```

where I'm imagining that you have a named branch called `production` that you want to publish to the server.